# CDK3 1 simple coding mutation/missense mutations (S106N) glioma

Tags: cancer

I found the below quotation in ([Peyressatre, 2015](https://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwikmqGjrNPYAhVG7GMKHduoBNEQFggpMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mdpi.com%2F2072-6694%2F7%2F1%2F179%2Fpdf&usg=AOvVaw25vdNzQHAruoeEjk3Nw-a1))

> CDK3   1 simple coding mutation/missense mutations (S106N)   glioma
>   [135]

The author has cited a database but not a paper. I want to find the paper that talks about the above mentioned type of mutation in CDK3

Comment: Welcome to SE Biology. Two points about your question. 1 "Peyressatre, 2015" does not allow anyone who doesn't already know to find the paper your quotation comes from. Please include a proper journal reference, perferably with a link. (Also to the database). 2. What effort have you made to search for this yourself and with what results? This sounds a very specialized question for this list. You must help anyone who is interested in the area to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Good question, if you check COSMIC and search for [S106N](http://cancer.sanger.ac.uk/cosmic/search?q=s106n), you'll find no hit with CDK3. So it isn't there (anymore?). One possibility is that it was present in 2014, when the paper was written, and the mutation is removed in the mean time by curation.

However, if you look at [genecards](http://www.genecards.org/cgi-bin/carddisp.pl?gene=cdk3#snp) and look for the variants, on top of the table you'll find a link to [expasy](http://web.expasy.org/variant_pages/VAR_041973.html). here they cite to a paper in [Nature](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed?cmd=search&term=17344846), and in the supplementary data of this paper you'll find your CDK3 S106N mutation.

Answer (score 0):

[UniProtKB: Cyclin-dependent kinase 3 (CDK3): *Homo sapiens*:](http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/Q00526) Natural variant: 106 S to N in a glioblastoma multiforme sample; somatic mutation: [1 Publication](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17344846) [Greenman et al. (2007) Nature 446: 153-158].